# Is it possible to export Wireshark syslogs to another device?

Tags: syslog, wireshark

My company is trying to export the live captured packet syslogs to a device within the network. We were just wondering if it is actually possible to do it with the Wireshark acting as a syslog relay server? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you trying to monitor what data is being sent to/from a syslog device? The .pcap file format is actually a generic capture format - you can do a capture on **any** device using **any** software and load it in Wireshark and it will be able to read it fine.

Comment: I have two questions - 1 do you need to do this in real time ? 2 if answer to one is yes, then why not capture the packets on the machine your relaying them to ?

Comment: Cause it will defeat the whole purpose of setting up a network infrastructure....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark syslogs? Do you mean the standard wireshark packet captures? If so, I don't know of any easy way to stream those messages to another server.

Have you considered using `tcpdump` instead? That's what wireshark uses under the hood, and it's a command-line program. This would make it quite easy to run tcpdump remotely via ssh and save the output to a file on the local system.

Comment: Yea I was referring to the packet Captures as we were thinking of transfering real time packet captures to another syslog server etc. Kiwi Server. Thanks.

Comment: something like this on the destination server `netcat -l 3030 | tcpdump -r -` and this on the source server `tcpdump -w - | netcat destserver 3030` would stream it, but I fail to see the point.

Comment: @c10k You're going to end up with some serious recursion issues there.

Comment: for sure, I had not put any filtering in the `tcpdump -w -` but you get the idea ;-)